# Rsync temporary file extension

Tags: rsync, filenames

I am having difficulties finding how Rsync "chooses" the extension for the temporary file created while copying the file if I don't use the --inplace option.

Example : 
I want to copy `sourceDirectory/myFile.txt` into `targetDirectory/` with Rsync.

While copying `myFile.txt` into `targetDirectory/` Rsync will create a file named `.myFile.txt.W4zvLi`  in `targetDirectory/`.

Then Rsync will rename `.myFile.txt.W4zvLi` into `myFile.txt`.

The question is how why Rsync uses the `W4zvLi` extension and why it seems to change each time I execute the Rsync program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rsync uses the `mktemp(3)` POSIX function to generate a unique temporary file name.  You pass a template string to the `mktemp` function, and it will return a file name with any `X` characters in the template replaced by a random character.

In particular, `rsync` passes `.XXXXXX` to `mktemp`.  If you want to try it out from the command line you can use the `mktemp(1)` binary like so:

```
mktemp -u "/tmp/foo.XXXXXX"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for

Answer (score 0):

man rsync:

```
Beginning with rsync 3.1.1, the  temp-file  names  inside
              the specified DIR will not be prefixed with an extra dot (though
              they will still have a random suffix added).
```

Comment: Explaining that the extension is chosen randomly might be a good idea.

Comment: Any clue about how the "random" suffix is calculated?

Comment: The clue is in the source of rsync and kernel.

Comment: The man quote refers to the specific case when temp files are created in a temp-dir specifed by the -T --temp-dir option. The default behavior seems to be unchanged in 3.1.1: temporary files starts with a dot in the same directory as the target file.