# inotifywait and rsync is printing temporary file names

Tags: bash, rsync, inotify

I am in the process of writing a bash script that will make a POST request to a remote server every time a new file is created in a directory. I use RSYNC to sync several directories to a main directory. The main directory is then being watched by `inotifywait` which will trigger a script execution when it detects new files.

The problem is the way RSYNC is creating the files I read here [Rsync temporary file extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321643/rsync-temporary-file-extension) that RSYNC uses `mktemp` which creates file names like `.filesynced.x12fj1` but will then rename them to `filesynced` after it has finished copying.

So in my `inotifywait` bash script I am getting the filenames of the temp files not the filename after it has been renamed. I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction so that I can get the filename after it has been moved and renamed.

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -m -q -e close_write /edi-files |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        # send contents of $file to api endpoint.
    done
```

CRON JOB:

```
*/1 * * * * rsync -avz --no-perms --no-o --no-g --remove-source-files /home/dir3/upload/ /home/dir2/upload/ /home/dir1/upload/ /edi-files/
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
The file '.xxxxxxx1.ATM.8I2mrS' appeared in directory '/edi-files/' via 'CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE'
The file '.xxxxxxx2.ATM.MnIMPP' appeared in directory '/edi-files/' via 'CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE'
The file '.xxxxxxx3.txt.3FSceN' appeared in directory '/edi-files/' via 'CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE'
The file '.xxxxxxx4.txt.GoIDCK' appeared in directory '/edi-files/' via 'CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE'
```

Comment: If you add `-e move` to inotifywait's command line, you'll also receive `MOVED_FROM` and `MOVED_TO` messages.